# Setting up a multiple dimensional parameter set in Origen?

Tags: origen-sdk

I have been using the [Origen parameters features](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/) and successfully created single dimension parameter sets dynamically as so:

```
      pcie.define_params "pcie_demphasis_#{a}_logvar_#{v}".to_sym, inherit: :logvar_default do |p|
        pcie.pcie_tx_p_pins.each_with_index do |(pin_id, pin_obj), i|
          p.tm.send("Variable#{i}.Name=", "var name1")
        end
      end
```

Is there a way to chain these sends together?  I have a 4-D data set that needs to be dynamically defined when importing data from Excel.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work, or do you mean something else?

```
p.tm.send("blah").send("blah2").send("blah3=", "blah3_val")
```